# Is it possible to disable all others event when an event was executing?

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener

For example i have some ***click*** event and while i trigger any selector's event, all other selector's event should be **disable** until current event finished executing.

I clicked on **selector-a** then repeatly clicked on **selector-b**

```
document.querySelector('.selector-a').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeOut(function() {
    console.log('event A');
  }, 500);
});

document.querySelector('.selector-b').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('event B');
});
```

My expected result:

```
event A
event B
event B
event B
.....
```

But actual result was:

```
event B
event A
event B
event B
.....
```

Some of my friends told me to use ***callback()*** but i don't think it can use with ***addEventListener***. Can anybody explain why i should use ***callback()*** or there is others way to solve this ?

Have a nice day everyone :)

Comment: Just use a variable, like `var blocked = false;` Now set it to true in your first event listener, and in your second, do a check: `if (blocked) return; // do nothing`

Comment: Easiest way is to add a variable `disabled` and change it to true/false on click as needed while checking the value before launching another click event.

Comment: I don't understand the question "*while i trigger any selector's event, all other selector's event should be disable until current event finished executing*" - you will NOT EVER get two events executed at the same time. Only one will run at a time. Even if multiple event handlers are triggered, they will run in sequence. "Some of my friends told me to use callback() but i don't think it can use with addEventListener" - you *have* callbacks - the functions you supply to `addEventListener` *are* callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual click event can't be prevented entirely, but the logic you're looking for can be achieved relatively easily - just set a boolean flag when you have something asynchronous that's running, and you can check it on every listener so that clicks can be ignored until the flag gets reset:

```
let somethingRunning = false;
document.querySelector('.selector-a').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (somethingRunning) return;
  somethingRunning = true;
  setTimeOut(function() {
    console.log('event A');
    somethingRunning = false;
  }, 500);
});

document.querySelector('.selector-b').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (somethingRunning) return;
  console.log('event B');
});
```

Note that completely synchronous handlers, like with `.selector-b`, don't need to reassign `somethingRunning`, because such a handler will always run to the end before another handler can run.

Answer (score 0):

In simple word it is not possible but by using some logic like flag we can but
suppose you have clicked 'selector a' and some operation is ongoing and same time you clicked on 'selector b' then you can avoid execution by flag but how will you ensure that when first's execution is over there should a mechanism to execute second click operation.

But to do avoid click whenever user click and some action is going on, add overlay on page so that user not able to access any actionable UI part.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you do not get your expected result is how javascript works. When you call **setTimout**` it will work asynchronous, so the function you passed in setTimout to will go to browser and after 500 milliseconds will be passed to the queue and then [event loop](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/) will do the checking of a stack if it is empty, when stack is empty it will start executing code from queue.

But for you to receive the expected result you can do it with a flag, if you use a flag (example `isWaiting`) the function from `.selector-b` will be interrupted until function from `.selector-a`is executed. Then it will enable you to run a function from `.selector-b`.
Like on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55843696/7028003).